# Vignere Encrypt/decrypt program in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

I'll get straight to the point:
I need to find a way to encrypt and decrypt a string of text using a Vigenère Cipher using Python3. I am trying to do this without downloading extra assets, but importing existing ones will be fine. A specific feature I want my program to have is that users will need to be able to enter the key they want to use inside the program itself. So far, I have managed to change letters into their values in the alphabet as well as back, but how do I do map this to the whole string while changing the key letter? *Code so far:*

```
with open("appbin/vignere.json", "rt") as vd:
    vigneredict = json.load(vd)
with open("appbin/encrypt.txt", "rt") as intx:
    inputtext = intx.read()
vignereword = input("Input the keyword for encrypting your text: ")
with open("appbin/vigkey.txt", "w") as kw:
    kw.write(vignereword)
textlist = list(inputtext)
```

This code loads in the text from a file called *encrypt.txt* and stores it, as well as making it into a list. How do I do the actual encrypting part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first make and store your key as a list, then Use a for loop like this

```
index = 0
for letter in textlist:
    #blah blah
    index += 1
    if index > len(keylist):
        index = 0
```

in place of blah blah put your method of converting the key and text letters to numbers (the index variable is for when you need to get the letter out of the keylist but I left that bit of the code for you to write), and add them together, subtracting 25 if the number is bigger than 25 then convert back to a letter and store in a new variable

Comment: Thanks! I need it for my IA (an assesment in computing)